# Is there a gender neutral equivalent of “manspreading”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, gender-neutral

Who knew that the term *manspreading* is considered deeply sexist?  I didn't

A nameless user proposed to delete the term from an answer of mine. His explanation was “remove misandry”. I had written

> [someone] who spreads their legs and invades your space (AKA manspreading)

The comment got me thinking. At first, I was quite flabbergasted and speechless. Agreed, the term is not complimentary, but I had considered it mainly to be a humorous term that was basically stating a truth. Men often do sit with their legs apart. It can show swagger, confidence, and suggest dominance. It can be due to their height, the taller the man, the more difficult it is for him to close his legs when seated in public transport.

*That's what I thought*

But according to one spinal neurosurgeon, John Sutcliffe, the reason is two-fold

> “The overall width of the pelvis is relatively greater in females and the angle of the femoral neck is more acute. These factors could play a role in making a position of sitting with the knees close together less comfortable in men,” he told The Independent.

and

> “I suspect most men would suggest the reason for adopting the more spread posture in sitting would be the avoidance of testicular compression from the thigh muscles. The pelvic rotation goes some way to improve compression in both aspects,” Sutcliffe continued.
>
> *[The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/manspreading-scientific-explanation-revealed-men-behaviour-public-transport-etiquette-a7862771.html)*

I suppose that makes sense. The phenomenon is dictated by physiological differences that are inherent in men and women's bodies.

I turned to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manspreading). It confirmed the user's standpoint, and why he suggested its removal

> **Both this posture and the use of the neologism "manspreading" have occasioned some internet criticism and debates in the US, UK, Turkey, and Canada.** The public debate began when an anti-manspreading campaign started on the social media website Tumblr in 2013; the term appeared a year later. OxfordDictionaries.com added the word ["manspreading"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/manspreading) in August 2015. Use of the term has been criticized as "a caricature of feminism" and the practice has been juxtaposed with examples of women taking up excessive space in public spaces with bags.

Further on, it supplies a female equivalent of the term

> The criticism and campaigns against manspreading have been counter-criticized for not addressing similar behavior by women, such as taking up adjacent seats with bags, or **"she-bagging"**.

So much controversy over a non-vulgar term, living in Italy I had no idea about the heated debate this term has sparked. So to make some sort of amends, I edited my answer and now it reads

> [someone] who spreads their legs and/or invades your space (AKA “manspreading” or “she-bagging”)

But it's not a perfect fit. And *she-bagging* doesn't work if you're talking about an airplane seat, does it?

- **What would be a gender-neutral equivalent of *manspreading*. A term that would not offend men, but could be applied to both sexes?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80738/discussion-on-question-by-mari-lou-a-is-there-a-gender-neutral-equivalent-of-ma). If you have something to say, put it in an answer. Any further discursive comments will be deleted without notice and with prejudice.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

#### Seat hog

Without having an example sentence, it's hard to suggest a perfect fit, but I would suggest "seat hog" or "seat hogging."

There's even a whole [blog](http://seathogs.com/) dedicated to posting pictures of this sort of people. (I tried to pick a photo with a non-obvious gender)
From that blog:

> SeatHog – noun – \ˈsēt-hog\ – a selfish or clueless individual who deprives another individual of any reasonable or unimpeded opportunity to sit down.

(In my dialect in regular IPA: `/ˈsi:tˌhɑg/`)

The sort of picture they share:

[image: A seat hog seen lounging back taking up two seats while another subway ride is forced to stand]

Washington state's [Sound Transit](https://www.soundtransit.org/)* uses "seat hog" to teach people how to ride the train. (Included the other ones because they're cute too.)

[image: Sound Transit seat graphics showing animals in correct and incorrect seated posture]

For readers unfamiliar with this use of "hog," it follows this [OED definition](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87576?rskey=vAlGrJ&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> [6] b. orig. U.S. Chiefly with modifying word: a person who appropriates or monopolizes something in a greedy and selfish manner. Cf. hog v.1 7b.

- Seattle metro area, the "Sound" refers to the Puget Sound, which lies directly west of Seattle.

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80783/discussion-on-answer-by-azor-ahai-is-there-a-gender-neutral-equivalent-of-mansp).

Comment: The sample sentence is *[someone] who spreads their legs and/or invades your space (AKA “manspreading” or "she-bagging")* The word I'm looking for goes in the parenthesis. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @MariLou Oh, okay, I guess I was looking for a complete sentence

Comment: Seat hog is something I have heard in the UK since I was quite young.  Some nice reference material, thank you.  Now I am tempted to go ask if there is a gender-neutral term for "acting like a big girl's blouse".

Comment: @TafT Ask away; as a US native, I have never heard that phrase before.

Answer (score 82):

To avoid the accusation of being biased and the ire of those who may be offended; a passenger who takes up too much room or invades their co-passenger's space could be termed a

- [**space hog**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hog)

> ‘Worse, they're also tremendous space hogs, gobbling up dozens of precious square feet in useless aisle area.’

The verb **hog** (hogged, hogging) is used indiscriminately, M-W says

> [to take in excess of one's due](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hog)
>   *hog the credit*

In fact, the term was already in use during the 1940s-50s

[image]
(1953)

> A whimsical, illustrated ad from the Tube (shown above) […] admonishing riders who are **hogging** seats. Even though the time, place, and design are very different, the message—it's really not cool to take up seats that should go to others who need them more—is crystal clear. [*Curbed*](https://ny.curbed.com/2016/3/11/11206942/transit-etiquette-manspreading-nyc-museum-exhibit)

[image] 
(1947)

Designed by Amelia Opdyke Jones for the New York City Subway, [these posters](https://untappedcities.com/2016/03/15/manspreading-in-nyc-and-around-the-world-ny-transit-museum-looks-at-transit-etiquette/) were in use for over 40 years beginning in 1918.

---

<sub>This answer, edited, was being composed when @Azor Ahai posted his answer "seat hog". My comments, first and foremost, thanking him and then apologising for posting a similar answer were deleted.</sub>

Comment: Nice references.  A handy way to show the longevity of the phrase and problem.  I wonder if I can dig out some old British railroad pamphlets that mention something similar.  I know there were things published and short articles in newspapers explaining expected behaviour.

Answer (score 38):

> sprawl
>   [sprawl]
>   verb (used without object)
>
> 1) to be stretched or spread out in an unnatural or ungraceful manner:
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sprawled)

## Example 1

> - ”I suppose only a man can man-spread their legs.”
> - ”Both a man or a woman can sit with their legs sprawled out.”

## Example 2

> - ”Can you give me some room on the bench. You are man-spreading, I can’t sit.”
> - “Can you give me some room on the bench. You are sprawled out, I can’t sit.”

Comment: This answer (sprawler) deserves more credit for being a completely gender and tone neutral non-colloquial descriptive term.  By comparison, the accepted answer is less specific, derogatory, colloquial, and a phrase rather than a word.

Comment: You can simply remove "man", too: ”Can you give me some room on the bench. You are spreading, I can’t sit.”

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That's not really idiomatic English, at least in the US.

Comment: @AzorAhai Perhaps adding "out" after spreading helps a bit.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It would, but I try not to assume it's bad in your dialect (I saw on your profile you were based in Ireland, and I know little about Hiberno English)

Comment: @AzorAhai English is not my mothertongue, I just attempted to address the issue by removing the prefix(?) "man", which was problematic. I was just a bit hasty and forgot to add "out".

Answer (score 17):

[Legs akimbo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/akimbo): knees bent and protruding from the trunk.

> a tailor sitting with legs akimbo

Comment: Though technically accurate, this particular phrase is probably usually associated with women and in a sexual context that isn't meant here. Examples: [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22legs+akimbo%22&oq=%22legs+akimbo%22), [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=legs%20akimbo).

Comment: @Dougal Oh gimme a break. UD _always_ has its head in the gutter.

Comment: Sure, UD is maybe a bad source, but it's not like that's [the only one](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-4110472/Nasty-wanna-Swimsuit-clad-Lena-Dunham-poses-legs-akimbo-reflects-future-Trump-world-learning-not-liked-all.html). It's definitely a nontrivial portion of the general Google results, and I think is generally not going to be as immediately-understood in context as the other answers anyway.

Comment: I'd say that Urban Dictionary is far too community driven and unmoderated to be considered a useful source. While it does include actual useful terms, they're so swamped in dross that it's nearly impossible to distinguish them from the background noise.

Comment: I always thought "akimbo" meant more like "Indian style" cross-legged/lotus/butterfly sitting...not like "manspread" sitting. (Realistically, most of the guys I know who sit "manspread" don't have the hip flexibility to comfortably sit in "Indian style".)

Comment: Many of the Google image search results in the link above do not show someone sitting with legs akimbo. It's a search fail.

Comment: I believe it was the Redwall series and "paws akimbo" that introduced me to this word, which would mean hands on hips in that context. Legs akimbo sounded terribly uncomfortable at first glance.

Answer (score 15):

No.

While there are words that carry the meaning of sitting in a way that takes up too much space, an essential part of the meaning of **manspreading** is the connection to a culture of male entitlement and the power dynamics of gender and personal space. If this is the meaning you intended to convey, you should keep it. It is not "misandry", and claims of "misandry" should be treated as highly suspect of being misogynist in nature (denying the reality of gendered power dynamics). There are cases where the word "misandry" is a meaningful criticism (e.g. denying that a man could be the victim of sexual assault or claims that men are not suitable as single parents) but this is not one of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80848/discussion-on-answer-by-r-is-there-a-gender-neutral-equivalent-of-manspreadin).

Answer (score 12):

How about "knee-spreading"? It doesn't cover the case where someone has excess bags but it could refer to any person of either gender who is sitting with their legs spread far apart.

Answer (score 9):

When discussing the issue as a comparative between the sexes on public transportation, one Slate writer used the term **legroom-encroaching jerk**

> So it seems that men and women alike prefer to travel with women,
>   generally perceived as less likely to be loudmouthed,
>   legroom-encroaching jerks. Do you disagree? You can tell me all about
>   it when you sit next to me on the train.

[Source](http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2013/09/16/on_planes_and_trains_everyone_prefers_to_sit_next_to_women.html)

Comment: Oh, I like that. That's quite good, very gender neutral!

Comment: Oh, dear. The quotation is kinda harking back to the stereotype of man = uncouth/inconsiderate.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't exactly unbiased. But she did find a suitable phrase there in the conclusion.

Comment: Perhaps one could usefully observe that both men and women prefer to travel with women because they are smaller and therefore take up less space. An airline once did some research on traveler complaints and found a correlation between how full a flight was and the number of complaints received about lack of space. (Who'd a thunk it?)

Comment: @BobRodes I'm not seeing how your comment is relevant to my answer. Perhaps  it would be better made in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80738/discussion-on-question-by-mari-lou-a-is-there-a-gender-neutral-equivalent-of-ma)

Comment: My comment is more addressed to the quote itself, perhaps. Its assertion, that men and women alike prefer to travel with women, suggests one reason for that is that men are "legroom-encroaching," and that because they are jerks. I offer an alternative explanation, although I can see I didn't explain that as carefully as I might have.